# Trimming spaces C++ POINTERS

Tags: c++, string, pointers, append

I wrote simple function to trim spaces in text in function `trim`.
It almost works. I have a problem because it should also change original string, but it doesn't. What is the problem? please describe. I appreciate any help. THANKS:)
CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

char* trim(char *str) {

    while(*str==' '){
        *str++;
    }

    char *newstr = str;

    return newstr; 
}


int main(){
    char str[] = "   Witaj cpp", *newstr;

    cout << "start" << str << "end" << endl;    // start   Witaj cppend

    newstr = trim(str);

    cout << "start" << str << "end" << endl;    // startWitaj cppend

    cout << "start" << newstr << "end" << endl;    // startWitaj cppend

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I have a problem because it should also change original string, but it doesn't.* --  Your function doesn't change anything or even attempt to change anything.  All it does is return a pointer.

Comment: so how could i modify the string without returning it, just working on a pointers?

Comment: I think you meant 'str++' instead of '*str++'; no deref there!

Comment: @jawjaw Please rethink this whole thing.  What if I pass you a pointer to char that was allocated with `new []`?  Your function (if you got it to work), would then move that pointer on me, and now when I call `delete [ ]`, the pointer has changed causing undefined behavior.  In any event, why do all of  this when you have `std::string` and the various algorithm and string functions to do this?

Comment: `char *newstr = str;` and `return newstr;` just does the same as `return str;`. The way you wrte that suggests to me that you're actively *trying* to copy the string, and that's the not way to do it. (you'd need `strcpy`).

Answer (score 1):

It **shouldn't** change the original string - even code like `*str=something;` doesn't apear.
To modify the original string, you can write like this

```
char* trim(char *str) {
    char* oldstr = str;

    while(*str==' '){
        str++;//*str++; // What's the point of that *
    }


    char *str2 = oldstr;

    while(*str!='\0'){
        *(str2++) = *(str++);
    }
    *str2 = '\0';

    return oldstr;


}
```

Comment: Should use `strcpy()`, if allowed

Comment: @AMomchilov you are right. I just want to echo to what I said, to make "*str=something;" apear

Answer (score 1):

Your present code is only searching for spaces.

You will need to replace the space character by characters that are not spaces.  This is often accomplished by copying the non-space characters to the first duplicate space.

Given:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
| P | e | a | r |   |   |   |   | f | r | u | i | t | '\0' |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

You want the result string to look like:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
| P | e | a | r |   |   |   |   | f | r | u | i | t | '\0' |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
                                  |  
                      +-----------+  
                      |  
                      V   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
| P | e | a | r |   | f | r | u | i | t | '\0' |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+
```

You would assign values by *dereferencing* your pointer.

After your `while` loop, you have:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
| P | e | a | r |   |   |   |   | f | r | u | i | t | '\0' |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
                  ^  
                  |  
str --------------+
```

So you would need another pointer that skips over the contiguous spaces:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
| P | e | a | r |   |   |   |   | f | r | u | i | t | '\0' |   
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+------+  
                      ^           ^  
                      |           |   
++str ----------------+           |  
                                  |  
non_space ------------------------+
```

Increment the destination pointer, `src`, then copy until end of string or a space character is found:

```
   ++str; // Skip past the first space.
   *str++ = *non_space;
```

If you use the C++ `std::string` type, you could use the `find_first_not_of` method to skip past whitespaces.

The `std::string` also has methods for removing characters from the string; and the `std::string` would move characters as necessary.